# How to run a command or script at screen lock/unlock?

Tags: command-line, bash

I am looking for a way to store lock/unlock screen times.

```
A=$(date)
echo $A >> $HOME/time_xprofile
```

What did I try:

```
$HOME/.bashrc
$HOME/.bash_logout
$HOME/.bash_prompt
$HOME/.xprofile
```

Then I locked the screen and checked whether file appeared and it failes every time. How can I check the time than?

Comment: As I read this question, I thought you were not running an X server. The answer you've selected is purely working  __while__ running an X server. Maybe you could describe your situation better...

Comment: FWIW, this question was also [asked on Unix/Linux stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28181/run-script-on-screen-lock-unlock).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following script will write lock/unlock time in a file `time_xprofile` in your home.

```
#!/bin/bash

dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'" | \
( while true
    do read X
    if echo $X | grep "boolean true" &> /dev/null; then
        echo "locking at $(date)" >> $HOME/time_xprofile
    elif echo $X | grep "boolean false" &> /dev/null; then
        echo "unlocking at $(date)" >> $HOME/time_xprofile
    fi
    done )
```

save the script. Give it execution permission.

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

**How to run**

```
./script.sh &
```

**Note** The script should run in back ground. Do not kill it. If you turn your screen lock/unlock while the script is running in background, your time of lock/unlock will be recorded in `time_xprofile` file at your home. **One can use it to run some command or script at screen lock/unlock.**

Mind that if you close the current terminal your script will be killed. You can use

```
nohup ./script.sh &
```

Then it will continue running even after closing the terminal.

**How to kill the script**

To kill the process, use in terminal

```
ps ax| grep "[s]cript.sh" | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs kill
```

<sub>Above script is inspired by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28183/52402)</sub>

Comment: Does it still working in ubuntu 17.10 with XServer? I don't know why is not working for me..

Comment: More than that: it only works a few times...

Comment: @eddieferetro I am still on 16.04 cannot test it for you. Why don't you ask a new question specifying your issues? Dbus event for screen lock may  be changed in 17.10

Answer (score 6):

In ubuntu 14.04 the DBus event for screen lock unlock has changed and the new script for binding to screen lock and unlock events looks like the following

```
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6'" | \
(
  while true; do
    read X
    if echo $X | grep "desktop-lock" &> /dev/null; then
      SCREEN_LOCKED;
    elif echo $X | grep "desktop-unlock" &> /dev/null; then
      SCREEN_UNLOCKED;
    fi
  done
)
```

Replace SCREEN_LOCKED and SCREEN_UNLOCKED with what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I used the same answer as [sourav c.](https://askubuntu.com/a/429728/589584), but first I run only `dbus-monitor --session "type='signal'"` in a terminal, and locked an unlocked my screen. Then, I could figure out the correct name for my operating system:

```
signal time=1680812432.954794 sender=:1.27 -> destination=(null destination) serial=3080 path=/org/xfce/ScreenSaver; interface=org.xfce.ScreenSaver; member=ActiveChanged
   boolean true
signal time=1680812435.757417 sender=:1.27 -> destination=(null destination) serial=3082 path=/org/xfce/ScreenSaver; interface=org.xfce.ScreenSaver; member=ActiveChanged
   boolean false
```

So, my command starts with `dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.xfce.ScreenSaver'"'` instead of `dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'"`.