# How to launch program on lock and close it on unlock

Tags: shortcut-keys, security, lock-screen, lock

Have siblings who like to "play" with my laptop by waking it from suspension and then typing random keys on the keyboard into the password field. Afterwards, they always deny it. I plan to install motion and only have it run while the computer is locked. After the computer is unlocked, the process should be killed. How would I go about launching motion when <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> is pressed and kill motion when the correct password is entered?

Answer (score 1):

I like your idea :)
But it seems like a duplicate: [Run script on screen lock/unlock (U&L Stack)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28181/run-script-on-screen-lock-unlock)
If you install `motion` correctly as a service, you should run `service motion start` at the lock-event and `service motion stop` at the unlock-event

Comment: I suggest you add an answer to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/429716/how-to-run-a-command-or-script-at-screen-lock-unlock) with that information :D

Comment: @Seth I'm not seeing the overlap. It's not about motion, its already looking at the same solution...

Comment: Ah, you're right. My bad at not noticing that :)