# locked Ubuntu screen - apps do not detect locked status

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, cinnamon

I use Ubuntu 12.10 but I did not really like Unity GUI because of performance issues and total inability to easily customize launcher. So I switched to Xubuntu, which is much faster BUT I have a problem, that our company messaging software is not able to detect when I lock the screen so it does not change my status to away. It works in Unity, but does not in Xfce nor in Cinnamon which I am testing right now. Is there any settings or command to make OS properly announce that screen was locked?

Comment: Perhaps this is a bug and you can post it on official bug tracker. A workaround could be a script similar like in this answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/429716/how-to-run-a-command-or-script-at-screen-lock-unlock given by souravc. –

Comment: cross-posted: http://superuser.com/questions/745905/locked-ubuntu-screen-apps-do-not-detect-locked-status