# How to run a script at screen lock / unlocks in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, scripts, lock-screen, screensaver

My problem is the same of this question but I am not able to get it working in ubuntu 17.10:

[How to run a command or script at screen lock/unlock?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429716/how-to-run-a-command-or-script-at-screen-lock-unlock)

I want to run a script that changes my keyboard RGB configuration at screen locks. The script runs flawless. The problem is to get the event of the locking/unlocking. I have try using dbus-monitor as said in that question and as said here:

https://people.gnome.org/~mccann/gnome-screensaver/docs/gnome-screensaver.html

So running this script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'" | \
( while true
    do read X
    if echo $X | grep "boolean true" &> /dev/null; then
        echo "locking at $(date)" >> $HOME/time_xprofile
    elif echo $X | grep "boolean false" &> /dev/null; then
        echo "unlocking at $(date)" >> $HOME/time_xprofile
    fi
    done )
```

But it only works... a few times(!).... I cannot understand what happens.

I'm using ubuntu 17.10 with ubuntu's gnome over X-server (no Wayland) and have try vanilla gnome and have the same problem.

I have try too:

```
dbus-monitor > out.log
```

To see ALL the traces that occur while locking/unlocking and it doesn't appear that signal... Only.... well... very few times...

I don't know what to do know, Any advice will be helpfull.

Comment: If you run in a terminal `dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'"`, does it toggle true/false on lock/unlock?

Comment: I tryed it before running dbus-monitor withouth parameters and no, it doesn't toggle true/false.

Comment: Ah, sorry, should have seen it in the question . I asked because it does work here though. (UB 17.10, mutter).

Comment: Can't test it on your system, but could you first run: `pgrep -f gnome-screensaver`, and subsequently: `sleep 10 && pgrep -f gnome-screensaver`, immediately lock screen, wait10-15 seconds and then unlock again. On my system `[1]` shows one pid, `[2]` shows two pids. That would be something to work with. If dbus is no option.

Comment: ^ works perfectly, and should be fine on all gnome-based systems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you're using Gnome then Nowadays I think it's better to listen to the `LockedHint` rather than screensaver messages. That way you're not tied to a screensaver implementation.

Here's a simple script to do that:

```
gdbus monitor -y -d org.freedesktop.login1 | grep LockedHint
```

Gives this:

```
/org/freedesktop/login1/session/_32: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged ('org.freedesktop.login1.Session', {'LockedHint': <true>}, @as [])
/org/freedesktop/login1/session/_32: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged ('org.freedesktop.login1.Session', {'LockedHint': <false>}, @as [])
```

Comment: I stole this idea and made it into a reusable script called `lockheed`. I'm running it within `systemd` to automate a few nice things when I unlock.

You can find the script here: https://github.com/gogama/lockheed.

Answer (score 3):

#### Use the existence of the process gnome-screensaver-dialog as an alternative trigger

If `dbus` is not possible or not preferred for whatever reason, you can use the existence of the process `gnome-screensaver-dialog` as a trigger. The process is called on lock screen.

In a python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import psutil
import time
import subprocess

procname = "gnome-screensaver-dialog"
lock_command = "/path/to/lockscript"
unlock_command = "/path/to/unlockscript"

lock1 = None

while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    lock2 = procname in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter())
    if lock2 != lock1:
        if lock2:
            subprocess.Popen(lock_command)
            print("locked")
        else:
            subprocess.Popen(unlock_command)
            print("unlocked")
        lock1 = lock2
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `locktoggle.py`
2. In the head section:

   ```py
   lock_command = "/path/to/lockscript"
   unlock_command = "/path/to/unlockscript"
   ```

   set the commands or paths to the scripts you'd like to run (leave the double quotes!)
3. Test- run the script with the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/locktoggle.py
   ```

N.B. In case you only run a command on either one of the events lock/unlock, simply comment out the corresponding line in the section:

```py
if lock2 != lock1:
    if lock2:
        # subprocess.Popen(lock_command)
        print("locked")
    else:
        # subprocess.Popen(unlock_command)
        print("unlocked")
```

Comment: It's a great idea but didn't worked for me :(. There's no gnome-screensaver-dialog. I think that it could be -and is only a theory- that ubuntu doesn't have, by default, screen-saver and it only has a login screen? I'll try at home instaling xscreensaver and using your solution that I found very clean and reusable.

Comment: @eddieferetro huh?? That is weird, gnome screensaver dialog, although the name suggests so, has nothing to do with screensaver, I don't have screensaver either.

Comment: @eddieferetro could you run `sleep 10 && pgrep -f gnome-screensaver`, immediately lock screen, wait10-15 seconds and then unlock again? See what the output is? Your distro is Gnome? (Ubuntu Gnome)

Comment: i'm cannot access my computer from here (proxies). I did what you say yesterday and didn't show any process number... :( is weird, I know, I'm going crazy with this... My distro is ubuntu 17.10 and the desktop is the default ubuntu-gnome... I'll retry this nigth to avoid the posibility of a human error... but I remember myself doin what you say and thinking on taking a screenshot because I know that you would find it incredible... as I found it...

Comment: @eddieferetro I'll install 17.10/Gnome in a VM. Curious to what I will see :)

Comment: Wasn't human error.